# in custom module ajax-loading form translations not working magento 2.3

Tags: module, ajax, forms, translate, magento2.3.2

*in ajax-loading form Change English it to italiano and it works but  italiano to English not working proper.*

*once transalte to italiano  then switch to english store not transalte to english language field seen in italiano*.

*also*

***Translate "This is a required field." in custom form not working***

*how to solved ? any idea ?*